# Ubuntu video app is dead,VLC fails to play videos[in Ubuntu on wayland]

Tags: 20.04, video, vlc, wayland, amdgpu

I recently installed and GPU pro driver. It works perfectly and is better than Ubuntu in build driver. On Ubuntu on Wayland environment,cannot start Ubuntu video player and when I open a video file using VLC player, it automatically closes. The Ubuntu video player says "could not open filexx.mp4 look for another app in store"  something like that. The other working environment works perfectly(Ubuntu budgie,gnome,X11)

Comment: Are you using VLC's snap package? Does filexx.mp4 exists out of `/home`?

Comment: VLC is installed from snap.The file location is in /home/downloads